# Application in application

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Suppose I have the following situation: We have a SPA containing many sub applications, with for example the following functions:

- See news
- Create products (upload a picture, set product info, etc)
- Check invoices
- Etc.

with the following directory structure (structure inspired by the book 'Marionette Gentle Introduction'):
-- Assets/
---- js/
------ app.js
------ apps/
-------- header/
-------- news/
-------- productcreate/
-------- invoice

The header contiains menu entries to all these sub-apps. Suppose that 'productcreate' is a very large (as in: lot of tasks) sub-application.

**Question**
I want to use this 'productcreate' sub-application both as a part of this larger application (really 'in' the application, with header above it etc) but also in a standalone setting. What would be the best way to approach this?

Would I for example need to develop these applications (the larger one and the productcreate one) seperately and is there a way to load an 'application in an application'?

Answer (score 0):

start with developing "productcreate" as a widget/app/whatever which can run stand-alone. and use that in main application when needed. Make sure sub-app and app follow pub-sub pattern, so that mainApp respond to sub-app events, if it is available, else nothing breaks. If you use requirejs loader, you can share common dependencies btw apps, and still load it only once.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me yet how to approach this. I can, of course, develop these applications seperately; however, I don't really see yet how you'd make them work together. It's not that they really need to communicatie, but i'd like to show this 'productcreate' application in a subview (region/itemview/w.e.) of the larger application.

Comment: @WilbertvandeRidder when you say application, I see it has some JavaScript working on a container, most probably a "div" element. If you have a sub-app which work within a div element, you can deploy it with any main-app, which accommodate a div to be used by sub-app.

Comment: That is indeed true. I can for example load a template in an Itemview which contains a certain ID on which I want to invoke another marionette application. However, I'm not entirely sure yet what's the best way to do that.